# Select a specific row in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Let's say i have a user table. And i got columns like ID, Username, Password and Activated.
All i want to know is how to write the MYSQL sentence :
SELECT into USERS WHERE ID = $ID, INSERT (activated) Values (0)
Can somebody say it in the right grammar?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29

Comment: Do you want to insert data or retrieve data ??

Answer (score 1):

You first need to connect to the MySQL database:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Then, to select data for an specific ID:

```
if( $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = $ID" ) ) {
    if( $result = $mysqli->use_result() ) {
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            echo $row['username'];
        }
        $result->close();
    }
}
```

To insert new data, you just need to query an insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this. Assuming your ID variable is $ID, table name is 'users' and column Activated is type INT.

To view it...

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID='".$ID."'");
```

To update it...

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET Activated=1 WHERE ID='".$ID."'");
```

Hows that for you?

Comment: SELECT * doesnt mean to select all?
and ID = $ID

Comment: Yes thats why I added a query to UPDATE a row as well (:

Comment: `$userId` variable changed to `$ID`

Comment: Hmm, mysqli query? Never heard :D

Comment: (mysql) functions are depreciating. Somebody is bound to comment after me with the good-explaination. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php - Read the red box

Comment: Anyway i figured it out :D it should be "UPDATE users SET Activated = 1 WHERE ID = $ID" Just like you said, thank you, i appreciate it ;)

Comment: Glad to help! I'd appreciate the answer accept and plus 1 if my answer helped you, thanks.

Comment: To be honest, dunno how to +1 you xD New Here

Comment: Click the up arrow next to the answer and click the tick underneath, if you think I have answered your question appropriately (:

Comment: I need 15 reputation, so sry xp